# pandas mean() results in INF?

Tags: pandas

```
df['C'] =   df['A'] / df['B']
df['C'].mean()
```

This returns a valid value.

However,

```
df['D'] =   df['B'] / df['A']
df['D'].mean()
```

returns inf.

Any thoughts on why? what does 'inf' mean here?

I downloaded the file and calculated the mean of 'D' in excel. it returned a valid value. there is no invalid values of 'D'.

Comment: What are df['b'] and df['a'] value wise?

Comment: You probably have one value that is `D` value that is `inf` so therefore the mean would be `inf`. Can you do `df[df['D'] == np.inf]` and see if that returns any rows?

Comment: it does have a few rows that fall under ```df[df['D'] == np.inf]```. what would cause that? why wouldn't they be NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a zero in one of your rows, which is creating issues. Consider the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,0],
                   'B' : [2,3,4,5]})
df['C'] = df['B'] / df['A']
df['D'] = df['A'] / df['B']
df
Out[1]: 
   A  B         C         D
0  1  2  2.000000  0.500000
1  2  3  1.500000  0.666667
2  3  4  1.333333  0.750000
3  0  5       inf  0.000000
```

Because, `df['A']` has a zero in it, when you do the calculation, `df['C'] = df['B'] / df['A']`, the result will be `inf` for the row where `A` = `0`. That is expected mathematically when 0 is on the denominator. However, when 0 is on the numerator, the result you would expect mathematically would be 0.

Therefore, when you take the `mean()` of multiple value and one value = `inf`, then the mean will be `inf`. This is also expected mathematically. The solution would be to replace `inf` values with `np.nan`:

```
df = df.replace(np.inf, np.nan)

Out[2]: 
   A  B         C         D
0  1  2  2.000000  0.500000
1  2  3  1.500000  0.666667
2  3  4  1.333333  0.750000
3  0  5       NaN  0.000000
```

Now, you are ready to get the means of each column. Full code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,0],
                   'B' : [2,3,4,5]})
df['C'] = df['B'] / df['A']
df['D'] = df['A'] / df['B']
df = df.replace(np.inf, np.nan)
df['C'].mean(), df['D'].mean()
Out[3]: (1.611111111111111, 0.47916666666666663)
```